# Permanently disable `org-indent-mode`?

Tags: org-mode, minor-mode

I can toggle `org-indent-mode` with `M-x org-indent-mode`, however I don't want it on by default. I tried, on my config file, `(org-indent-mode -1)`, but I get a "undefined symbol" error. I also tried using `setq` instead, despite Emacs' wiki saying to use the function not the variable. I also tried `(setq auto-indent-start-org-indent nil)` because a website said this was the way, but it also didn't work. I am using Emacs 24.4.1 on Debian.

Answer (score 2):

In your init file, you might have to require the library first:

```
(require 'org-indent)
(org-indent-mode -1)
```