# How to turn off automatic indenting for Org files in a specific folder?

Tags: org-mode, indentation

I am using Doom Emacs. I like having indentation for most of my org files, but I have one folder where I want to have org files without indenting, to use for writing documents.

I have already tested adding `#+STARTUP noindent`, and that works per file, but I'm trying to find a way to make it the default for the folder.

I used `add-dir-local-variable`, to set `org-indent-mode` to `nil`, and I can see that was written to a `.dir_locals.el` in the folder I want to make the change for. But when I open an Org file it is still indented. If, after the file is open, I manually toggle `org-indent-mode`, I can turn the indenting on and off. Seems like maybe a matter of the sequence or I'm going about this the wrong way. If it helps, here is the `.dir_locals.el`

```lisp
;;; Directory Local Variables
;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")

((org-mode
  (org-indent-mode nil)))
```

Comment: Similar: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22524/permanently-disable-org-indent-mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C-h v org-indent-mode RET` says (emphasis added):

> If called interactively, enable Org-Indent mode if ARG is
> positive, and disable it if ARG is zero or negative.  If called
> from Lisp, **also enable the mode if ARG is omitted or nil**, and
> toggle it if ARG is ‘toggle’; disable the mode otherwise.

You probably want to say (edited as per the OP's answer to avoid misleading future visitors):

```el
((org-mode . ((eval . (org-indent-mode -1)))))
```

in your `.dir-locals.el` file.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you [NickD](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14825/nickd) for your help, it got me to the right answer! Doing exactly what is listed above worked when added to the Doom Emacs `config.el` but not in the `.dir-locals.el`. To make it work as a directory variable, adding an `eval` seems to have done the trick. Here is my updated `.dir-locals.el'`

```lisp
;;; Directory Local Variables
;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")

((org-mode . ((eval . (org-indent-mode -1)))))
```

Comment: Right - this is a local variables file after all. I'll fix up my answer to avoid misleading future visitors. Thanks!